# Nginx rewrite after changing location's root

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm using Nginx and make a small conf file like this :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com;
  root /var/www/script;

  location /something {
      root /var/www/another_script/;
      rewrite /something/(.*)$ /index.php?var=$1;
  }
}
```

the problem appear with the rewrite rule which go back to the `/var/www/script` instead of `/var/www/another_script`

Can i rewrite to the new root of the location ? or it's impossible ?

Thanks in advance .

p.s : someone maybe suggest to use `alias` rather than `root` , but it's not the real problem.

Comment: Is it an alternative to drop the use of the `root`-parameter in the server-block and explicitly define it in all location-blocks?

Comment: I try it too :) , Nginx will use the `/etc/nginx/html/` as a root

Comment: Which `index.php` do you want to load? You specified `/index.php` which is of course located in `/var/www/script`. Do you want `/something/index.php` instead, which is located in `/var/www/another_script`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes that what i want

Answer (score -1):

The `root` directive does not apply outside of the `location` it is in.

If you want to rewrite one `location` into another `location` and change the `root`, then you have to specify such `root` within the latter `location`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i don't want to rewrite to another location i want to rewrite inside my location .